# How to use switch case to put the a value contains a string into right object in array?

Tags: javascript

I have an `data` array which looks like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "season": "autumn",
        "firstContactPersonName": "John",
        "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
        "secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
        "secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644"
    },
    {
        "season": "christmas",
        "firstContactPersonName": "Tommy",
        "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
        "secondContactPersonPhone": "Thomas"
    },
    {
        "season": "winter",
        "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
        "firstContactPersonName": "Peter",
        "secondContactPersonName": "Tom",
        "secondContactPersonPhone": "44664455"
    }
  ]
}
```

But sometimes there might be:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "season": "christmas",
        "firstContactPersonName": "Tommy",
        "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
        "secondContactPersonPhone": "Thomas"
    },
    {
        "season": "autumn",
        "firstContactPersonName": "John",
        "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
        "secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
        "secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `data` array can change.

I have another array that contains some dates. They have following dates in the array:

`const dateArray = ["christmas=2020-12-28", "autumn=2020-08-28", "winter=2020-02-28"]`.

And sometimes there can be const dateArray = ["christmas=2020-12-28", "autumn=2020-08-28"]

How can i insert these dates in the `data` array into right object without actually telling which position the object is in? How can i find which position the `autumn`, `christmas` or the `winter` is in and then put the right date into the right object? And what if i add new object to the `data` array? In other words, i need some dynamic method to handle it for me. SO i can add new keys before `=` to the date and insert to the right object in `data` array.

Comment: Your data array only contains 3 items ? Also if you were to change it to an object your life would be much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = [
    {
        "season": "autumn",
        "firstContactPersonName": "John",
        "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
        "secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
        "secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644"
    },
    {
        "season": "christmas",
        "firstContactPersonName": "Tommy",
        "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
        "secondContactPersonPhone": "Thomas"
    },
    {
        "season": "winter",
        "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
        "firstContactPersonName": "Peter",
        "secondContactPersonName": "Tom",
        "secondContactPersonPhone": "44664455"
    }
  ]

const dateArray = ["christmas=2020-12-28", "autumn=2020-08-28", "winter=2020-02-28"]
let updatedData = data.map((x)=> {
  let season = x.season;
   x.date = dateArray.find(e=> e.indexOf(season) > -1).split("=")[1];
  return x;
  })
                           

console.log(updatedData)
```

Comment: So if i add a new object in `data` array with name "easter", and i have a new date in `dateArray` with this name `easter=2020-04-20`, then i have to modify the code to fix it, How can i handle it dynamically ?

Comment: Yep, I have updated the snippet above to handle it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

not with a switch, but this is a way to do that:

```js
  dateArray.forEach(date => {
        if (date.includes("autumn")) {
          data.data[0] = { ...data.data[0], date };
        } else if (date.includes("christmas")) {
          data.data[1] = { ...data.data[1], date };
        } else if (date.includes("winter")) {
          data.data[2] = { ...data.data[2], date };
        }
      });
```

Comment: I see that you have ...data.data[0], and insert the object in there. But what if its not same order? I have edited the question